# Data Frame Subset Performance

Tags: performance, r, dataframe, subset

I have a couple of large data frames (1 million+ rows x 6-10 columns) I need to subset repeatedly. The subsetting section is the slowest part of my code and I curious if there is way to do this faster.

```
load("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4131944/Temp/DF_IOSTAT_ALL.rda")
start_in <- strptime("2012-08-20 13:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
end_in<- strptime("2012-08-20 17:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
system.time(DF_IOSTAT_INT <- DF_IOSTAT_ALL[DF_IOSTAT_ALL$date_stamp >= start_in & DF_IOSTAT_ALL$date_stamp <= end_in,])

> system.time(DF_IOSTAT_INT <- DF_IOSTAT_ALL[DF_IOSTAT_ALL$date_stamp >= start_in & DF_IOSTAT_ALL$date_stamp <= end_in,])
   user  system elapsed 
  16.59    0.00   16.60 

dput(head(DF_IOSTAT_ALL))
structure(list(date_stamp = structure(list(sec = c(14, 24, 34, 
44, 54, 4), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), mon = c(7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), year = c(112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L
), wday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), yday = c(232L, 232L, 232L, 
232L, 232L, 232L), isdst = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"
), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), cpu = c(0.9, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 
0.2, 0.1), rsec_s = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), wsec_s = c(0, 3.8, 0, 
0.4, 0.2, 0.2), util_pct = c(0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0), node = c("bda101", 
"bda101", "bda101", "bda101", "bda101", "bda101")), .Names = c("date_stamp", 
"cpu", "rsec_s", "wsec_s", "util_pct", "node"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'm sure you can do it faster, but the best method is going to depend on the structure of `DF_IOSTAT_ALL`.  Can you provide a small sample of that object?  E.g. the output from `dput(head(DF_IOSTAT_ALL))`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I added the requested output. Sorry for not including the first time.

Comment: What kind of subsets are you doing?

Comment: Out of interest, how slow is this?

Comment: @BlueMagister I'm subsetting it to time slices. It's performance data from iostat on a cluster of machines. I have begin and end times for some performance test. So, I want to subset this to just the timeframe of the test then graph it. Hope this is what you were asking..

Comment: @James I just updated with a link to the actual rda file and the timing from my laptop (Core i7, 32 GB of RAM) of 16 seconds. I have 3 of these large data frames which take ~ 60 seconds for all 3. I have 40 time slices to analyze and graph. If this was a one-off project, I'd get over it, but a lot more people in my org could use this code and I'd like it to be a little faster. I could easily stick in a database and partition by day or hour or index it, but didn't want the dependency on a database for this.

Comment: My hunch is that you can make this faster by adding a column of time categories using the function `cut`, and then take advantage of the the sorted key properties of `data.table` to make subsetting faster.

Comment: @TylerMuth Nice machine! I'm surprised it's taking that long. You might want to try `debug`ging your code to see what is taking the most time. As I see that your time values seem to be ordered, you *might* get some speed-up by using `which` to find the start and end rows rather than testing all elements.

Answer (score 1):

I would use xts for this.  The only potential hiccup is that xts is a matrix with an ordered index attribute, so you can't mix types like you can in a data.frame.

If the node column is invariant, you can just exclude it from your xts object:

```
library(xts)
x <- xts(DF_IOSTAT_ALL[,2:5], as.POSIXct(DF_IOSTAT_ALL$date_stamp))
x["2012-08-20 00:00:24/2012-08-20 00:00:54"]
```

Update using the OP's actual data:

```
Data <- DF_IOSTAT_ALL
# change node from character to numeric,
# so it can exist in the xts object too.
Data$node <- as.numeric(gsub("^bda","",Data$node)
# create the xts object
x <- xts(Data[,-1], as.POSIXct(Data$date_stamp))
# subset one day
system.time(x['2012-08-20 13:00/2012-08-20 17:00'])
#    user  system elapsed 
#       0       0       0
# subset 13:00-17:00 for all days
system.time(x['T13:00/T17:00'])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    2.64    0.00    2.66
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are my experiments with `data.table`. Interestingly, just the conversion to `data.table` will make your lookups faster, possibly through more efficient lookup to the logical vectors. I compared four things: the original data frame lookup; a lookup with conversion from POSIXlt to POSIXct (thanks to Matthew Dowle); the data table lookup; and the data table lookup in addition to the setup of copy and conversion. Even with the additional setup, the data table lookup wins. With multiple lookups, you'll get even more savings in time.

```
library(data.table)
library(rbenchmark)
load("DF_IOSTAT_ALL.rda")
DF_IOSTAT_ALL.original <- DF_IOSTAT_ALL

start_in <- strptime("2012-08-20 13:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
end_in<- strptime("2012-08-20 17:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#function to test: original
fun <- function() DF_IOSTAT_INT <<- DF_IOSTAT_ALL.original[DF_IOSTAT_ALL.original$date_stamp >= start_in & DF_IOSTAT_ALL.original$date_stamp <= end_in,]
#function to test: changing to POSIXct
DF_IOSTAT_ALL.ct <- within(DF_IOSTAT_ALL.original,date_stamp <- as.POSIXct(date_stamp))
fun.ct <- function() DF_IOSTAT_INT <<- DF_IOSTAT_ALL.ct[with(DF_IOSTAT_ALL.ct,date_stamp >= start_in & date_stamp <= end_in),]
#function to test: with data.table and POSIXct
DF_IOSTAT_ALL.dt <- as.data.table(DF_IOSTAT_ALL.ct);
fun.dt <- function() DF_IOSTAT_INT <<- DF_IOSTAT_ALL.dt[date_stamp >= start_in & date_stamp <= end_in,]
#function to test: with data table and POSIXct, with setup steps
newfun <- function() {
    DF_IOSTAT_ALL <- DF_IOSTAT_ALL.original;
    #data.table doesn't play well with POSIXlt, so convert to POSIXct
    DF_IOSTAT_ALL$date_stamp <- as.POSIXct(DF_IOSTAT_ALL$date_stamp);
    DF_IOSTAT_ALL <- data.table(DF_IOSTAT_ALL);
    DF_IOSTAT_INT <<- DF_IOSTAT_ALL[date_stamp >= start_in & date_stamp <= end_in,];
}
benchmark(fun(), fun.ct(), fun.dt(), newfun(), replications=3,order="relative")

#      test replications elapsed   relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
#3 fun.dt()            3    0.18   1.000000      0.11     0.08         NA        NA
#2 fun.ct()            3    0.52   2.888889      0.44     0.08         NA        NA
#4 newfun()            3   35.49 197.166667     34.88     0.58         NA        NA
#1    fun()            3   66.68 370.444444     66.42     0.15         NA        NA
```

If you know what your time intervals are beforehand, you can probably make it even faster by splitting with `findInterval` or `cut` and keying/indexing the table.

```
DF_IOSTAT_ALL <- copy(DF_IOSTAT_ALL.new)
time.breaks <- strptime.d("2012-08-19 19:00:00") + 0:178 * 60 * 60 #by hour
DF_IOSTAT_ALL[,interval := findInterval(date_stamp,time.breaks)]
setkey(DF_IOSTAT_ALL,interval)

start_in <- time.breaks[60]
end_in <- time.breaks[61]
benchmark(a <- DF_IOSTAT_ALL[J(60)],b <- fun2(DF_IOSTAT_ALL))
#                  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
#1 DF_IOSTAT_ALL[J(60)]          100    0.78 1.000000      0.64     0.14         NA        NA
#2  fun2(DF_IOSTAT_ALL)          100    6.69 8.576923      5.76     0.91         NA        NA
all.equal(a,b[,.SD,.SDcols=c(12,1:11,13)]) #test for equality (rearranging columns to match)
#TRUE
```

Comment: Interesting. Not sure but isn't `fun` slow on `DF_IOSTAT_ALL.original` because `date_stamp` is type `POSIXlt`; i.e. `data.frame` would be faster too on `POSIXct` instead?`POSIXlt` is really terrible for performance (apx 40 bytes per date iirc!) Also `newfun` will be much faster doing `as.data.table` instead of `data.table` and then followed by `DF_IOSTAT_ALL[,date_stamp:= as.POSIXct(date_stamp)]`. The `$<-` in `newfun` will be copying the whole of the dataset.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I'll see how the lookups change when I change the original data frame to `POSIXct`. I tried `DF_IOSTAT_ALL[,date_stamp:= as.POSIXct(date_stamp)]` but I got an error out of it (possibly a bug with `POSIXlt` classes as data table columns)?

Comment: On the error, oh yes, I see now. In that case just start off with `POSIXct` in the `data.frame` and forget `POSIXlt` as early as possible.