# Most efficient way of subsetting dataframes

Tags: performance, r, dataframe, subset

Can anyone suggest more efficient way of subsetting dataframe without using `SQL/indexing/data.table` options?

I looked for similar questions, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479238/data-frame-subset-performance) suggests indexing option.

Here are ways to subset with timings.

```
#Dummy data
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(1000000, 1, 1000), y=runif(1000000, 1, 1000))

#Subset and time
system.time(x <- dat[dat$x > 500, ])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.092   0.000   0.090 
system.time(x <- dat[which(dat$x > 500), ])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.040   0.032   0.070 
system.time(x <- subset(dat, x > 500))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.108   0.004   0.109
```

**EDIT:**
As Roland suggested I used [microbenchmark](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/microbenchmark/index.html). It seems `which` performs the best.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("microbenchmark")

#Dummy data
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(1000000, 1, 1000), y=runif(1000000, 1, 1000))

#Benchmark
res <- microbenchmark( dat[dat$x > 500, ],
                       dat[which(dat$x > 500), ],
                       subset(dat, x > 500))
#plot
autoplot.microbenchmark(res)
```

[image]

Comment: I am curious, Why the restriction of not using `data.table` subsetting or `xts` indexing?

Comment: It really depends on the specifics. In your example the generic advice would be to make `dat` a matrix and work with that. But if you want something as general and safe as `[.data.frame` you won't find anything better.

Comment: It looks like you already have an answer to your question. The first solution seems to be more efficient than the others

Comment: @agstudy because `data.table` and `xts` are the obvious ways to go about it :) I would want to find out if there are any other ways to subset a `data.frame` which are more efficient than the ones already mentioned.

Comment: @zx8754 Maybe if you give more context of the question (Personally, I dislike dealing with performance without a timing target for a specific job/process) you will be more lucky to get an answer.

Comment: @agstudy It just a curiosity, someone mentioned that `dat[dat$x > 500, ]` is not efficient, and I couldn't think of any better way of subsetting.

Comment: @zx8754 Juste coerce it as a matrix and you will improve the performance by at lest a factor of 2. data.frame is slower because it is a multi type container...

Comment: @PAC you mean the second maybe not the first? btw I got the same timing for the first but 0.03 for the second and the same again for the third (I guess because my system time is always zero...)

Comment: I'm not quite sure but I think that the system time is a better indicator of efficiency.

Comment: Benchmarking (using package microbenchmark) shows that the second approach is (surprisingly) faster than the first approach by a factor of 3.

Comment: @zx8754, if you feel you have found an answer on your own with the suggestions in the comments, please post it as an answer and accept it to clearly show others that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Roland suggested I used microbenchmark. It seems `which` performs the best.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("microbenchmark")

#Dummy data
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(1000000, 1, 1000), y=runif(1000000, 1, 1000))

#Benchmark
res <- microbenchmark( dat[dat$x > 500, ],
                       dat[which(dat$x > 500), ],
                       subset(dat, x > 500))
#plot
autoplot.microbenchmark(res)
```

[image]